# C/C++ SSL Request to CXF Server

Tags: java, c++, spring, tomcat, ssl

First of all, I have developed a web server by using cxf-spring-json-tomcat. Although, I created JKS keystore file and configured my tomcat server for using SSL connection. And, I can request to my server by using chrome, firefox.

My Server Bean:

```
@Service
@Path("/tservice")
public class TestService {


    @GET
    @Path("/{message}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response find(@PathParam("message") String message)
    {
        Result result = new Result();
        result.setMessage(message);
        result.setResultId(Math.random());
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(result).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }

}
```

Tomcat server.xml (SSL)

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               maxThreads="200" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="/home/**/.keystore" keystorePass="123456"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

My question is that(for server side) I have to make another configuration or add code part for ssl in my java classes?

Another question for client side is that;

I need to develop C/C++ client application by using SSL connection. What should I consider? Are there any tricks for them? Any suggestion,example or tutorial?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configure the SSL in tomcat , So tomcat handles SSL request.No need to change any code in server side.

Comment: What about client side with C/C++?

Comment: I dont know about the C/C++ .But once server is SSL any client can call it irrespective of your client.

Comment: create another thread for c++.Do some R&D and coding before posting any question to statckoverflow because if ask "I need to develop C/C++ client application by using SSL connection. What should I consider? Are there any tricks for them? Any suggestion,example or tutorial?" Then guys minus the questions.